# RegEx Or with Wildcard not matching

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match a string like "    23.0     32.0". Here's my regex:

```
hrs_pnt_regex = /\s{2,}-?\d{1,2}\.\d(\s+|$)/
```

Code:

```
x = "    23.0     32.0"
x.to_enum(:scan, hrs_pnt_regex).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

Result:

```
 MatchData "    23.0     " 1:"     "
```

What I notice is that the \s+ doesn't seem to work in the parens at the end. If I change it to "\s\s", it matches both numbers like so. Otherwise I get only the first one.

```
<MatchData "    23.0  " 1:"  ">, <MatchData "   32.0" 1:"">
```

Does + not work with a | after it?

Comment: Why `.to_enum` here? That seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: I found that as a way to get all the MatchData objects when you want to want to apply a regex globally to a string. Otherwise it will just return the string matches with no object that gives you the string's start position.

Comment: If you do a `match` with a `/g` flag you should get all the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `(\s+|$)` part is consuming the spaces that subsequent matches need to identify the starting part. You're basically sabotaging your next round by gobbling up all those spaces and leaving the pointer at the `3` position at the start of `32.0`. So long as they're considered part of the first match, they won't be available for the second.

A quick fix is:

```
x.scan(/\s{2,}(-?\d{1,2}\.\d)/)
# => [["23.0"], ["32.0"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is to use an online Regex Matcher. My favorite is [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Best I can tell from your description is you want to match numbers simular to `xx.y`, in which case

```
hrs_pnt_regex = /\d{2,}\.\d{1,2}/
```

will match both sets, `23.0` and `32.0`